# Move MySQL Database to Amazon EC2 Servers

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a website which has a 5 GB big mysql database.

I am thinking if it is a good idea to move only the database to amazon, all front-end etc. (PHP) will remain.

I've red already a lot about my Idea and I am not sure whether it is a good idea. Some people say its not a good idea to move a database file to EC2, I will need ECB for a relational Database file like MySQL.

And the amazon FAQ etc. are filled with so much informations I can hardly decide what is important and whats not.

Someone can comment on this? That would be helpful.

P.S.: I am not the owner the main person is to busy atm. and asked me to do the research.

Thanks! I hope I am not off-topic. If so I am sorry, provide me then the right StackExchange where to post such a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with moving a database to AWS EC2.  IN the end, they're just servers, but they're set up in a very specific way.

You have to be fully aware of the limitations of the platform before you start, so those documents that you don't know where to start?  Read them all.

You've got to be aware that there are different ways of working when you start using AWS.  Some fundamental differences between having a server in your server room that you are in complete control of vs a server in AWS' data centre somewhere that somebody else is in control of.

Learn about RDS, learn about different storage types, learn about EC2.  Make sure you understand the costs before you put anything in there.

Use the free year's worth of free instances for all it's worth.  Test, ensure that what you want to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful to research what kind of AMI (image) you select for your EC2 instances. Note that there is a huge range in image size, and the cost correlates to some extent with the image size. 
It is also important to note that some AMIs come with specific software (Java, Tomcat, etc.) preinstalled, so you may want to look into that as well. Here is a link to some documentation on setting up MySQL on an AMI, in any case -- hope that helps!
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ha-vm-aws-setup.html